# Heroku H99 Errors, Server not resolving

Tags: node.js, heroku

Getting `503 Service Unavailable` and `504 Gateway Timeout` responses from a Heroku-hosted server since last night, which appears to coincide with a platform issue on [status.heroku.com](http://status.heroku.com/).

In the logs, I'm seeing a H99 error, which appears to indicate a Heroku Platform error. Heroku.Router is the source of the error. [H99 Platform Error](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h99-platform-error)

Output from `heroku logs`:

```
<timestamp> heroku[router]: Error H99 (Platform error) -> GET 
<app>.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Updated code before it went down, which triggered a re-deploy, however there were no application changes that could cause downtime, the application should run the same as before. Having no issues on local environments.

As it's the weekend, there's no support from Heroku, plus this is hosted on their free tier (one web dyno). It appears at this stage there's nothing to be done this end, as the error is described as an internal issue on Heroku's side.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually managed to resolve this issue in two ways.

The easiest solution was upgrading from their free tier and scaling the application to two dynos. There's a difference in the way Heroku hosts free and paid tier applications, which brought the server back live with minimal effort. Haven't tried downgrading at this stage, it may actually stay up if I scaled the application down again to one dyno.

Given the cost incurred above, that had to be approved, the second solution was re-deploying the codebase to a new application hosted on Heroku's free tier. This worked but required greater effort copying attached add-ons, etc. The last step here would have been to point the DNS at the new application.

Reading around, scaling from free tier to paid tier can make a difference. Scaling within paid tier, on the other hand, is not recommended, and doesn't appear to resolve downtime issues.

Given the hassle of weekend downtime, and lack of documentation around the problem, I'm sharing this here!

Comment: There's no difference between free and paid - except that a single (free) dyno will idle whilst more than 1 dyno won't idle.

Comment: From reading up on this process, the idle state appears to be processed differently, and seemingly more error-prone. I was referring to the idle state, though, yes.